# Implementation, Macros or the package code, at the end of the package, For what?

Tags: macros, package-writing

could i use the codes in Implementation section in my document, or this how the author built the package?

and why the code lines in Implementation section are numbered?

For example: from tabularx package
[image]

Comment: if you mean when looking at a typeset dtx file then the implementation section is the source code for the package, not commands to use in the document.

Comment: from the package file, from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/:A

Comment: Normal users of LaTeX (and most others, too) can safely ignore the appendix of the documentation where the code of the package is listed/documented

Comment: oh that's my code:-) yes that is the internal implementation of the package you should never need to read that unless you are interested in how the package works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation section is the same as the dtx file. also the \newcommend -in implementation section- are defaults, and i can edit them by \renewcommand in my preamble.

Answer (score 2):

In the normal conventions of packages documented using the doc package `.dtx` mechanism, the implementation section is the source code of the package. there is usually an option to typeset just the user-level documentation without this section but most pre-built pdf include it. It is useful if you are interested in how the package works or need to debug some error, but it is not intended to be read by people simply using the package.

The line numbers can be referenced within the text (eg in the command index) to refer to lines where specific commands are used.